# Recursive function for listing directories

Tags: c#, recursion, directory

The below code is recursive function that list directories in 2 levels:

```
static  Dictionary<string,string> pList=new Dictionary<string, string>(); 
static void ListDirec(string path, int start, int end)
{
    var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    var folders = dirInfo.GetDirectories().ToList();

    foreach (var item in folders)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(start * 4, ' ') + item.Name);
        if (start < end) {
            ListDirec(item.FullName, start + 1, end);
        }
    }
}
```

Now how can optimize that in this case?

For example, I've these directories with their sub-directories:

```
folder-A
    folder-A-1
    folder-A-2
    folder-A-3
folder-B
    folder-B-1
    folder-B-2
    folder-B-3
folder-C
    folder-C-1
    folder-C-2
    folder-C-3
```

Now I want save parents as key and children as value in dictionary, with their relation for example folder-A has these children: folder-A-1, folder-A-2, folder-A-3 and so on.

What's the best way to do that in this function?

Comment: You are asking for help in writing code to add the data to a dictionary. This code does not exist yet, so it is not ready for a Code Review. When your code works as designed, bring it back for review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To relate your parent directories to their children, you could have `plist` declared like this:

```
static Dictionary<String, List<String>> plist = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

Each time you hit a child folder, you add its name to

```
Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(start * 4, ' ') + item.Name);
string parent = path.Split('\\').Last();
if (!pList.Keys.Contains(parent))
    pList.Add(parent, new List<string>());
pList[parent].Add(item.Name);
```

Sorry, I don't have access to a C# compiler at the moment so I can't verify this 100%, but it's a starting point at least.

**Edit**: After thinking about it, I don't think C# likes it if you use `[]` before an element is in the Dictionary.  I edited the above code to include how to get the `parent` and included the Console.WriteLine so you know where I would put it.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a `Dictionary<DirectoryInfo, List<DirectoryInfo>>`.  This way if you want to access the directories the methods you need are right there:

```
public static Dictionary<DirectoryInfo, List<DirectoryInfo>> BuildTree(string path)
{
    Dictionary<DirectoryInfo, List<DirectoryInfo>> temptree = new Dictionary<DirectoryInfo, List<DirectoryInfo>>();
    //If you need to filter the results edit the search string
    foreach(DirectoryInfo dir in new DirectoryInfo(path).GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
    {
        temptree.Add(dir, dir.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList());
    }
    return temptree;
}
```

If you would like a LINQ option you could do it this way:

```
public Dictionary<DirectoryInfo, List<DirectoryInfo>> BuildTree(string path)
{
    Dictionary<DirectoryInfo, List<DirectoryInfo>> temptree = (from dir in new DirectoryInfo(path).EnumerateDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                                                                select dir).ToDictionary(x => x, x => x.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList());
    return temptree;
}
```